# Solving non-homogenous linear constant coefficient ODE by factoring

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was thinking about non-homogenous linear ODEs and I noticed this method of doing them, but I don't know what it's called and can't seem to find it anywhere. Does anyone know if this works?:

Like most methods of solving, look for a particular solution first: rewrite $y'' + 4y' + 3y$ as the operator $(D^2 + 4D + 3)$ applied to y, and factor this. So we can rewrite $y'' + 4y' + 3y = e^t$ as $(D+1)(D+3)y = e^t$. Then we can solve $(D+3)y = e^t$ as a first-order linear ODE for 1 particular solution $y_{particular 1}$. Then solve $(D+1)y = y_{particular 1}$ for $y_{particular}$. (So $y_{particular 1}$ is a temporary thing, $y_{particular}$ is what we were looking for).

(For higher orders, we could keep going)

I couldn't find this method when I looked at my course's notes or online, but it seems simpler and more motivated. Does anyone know if this works and what it's called?

Comment: Is not a variation of the undetermined coefficient ? (c.f: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilator_method)

Comment: I should point out that the way it's presented, the order in which you do the solving is backward: you would first solve $(D+1)y_1 = e^t$ for $y_1$ and then solve $(D+3)y = y_1$. Basically, you go outermost-to-innermost. It doesn't matter here, though since $D+1$ and $D+3$ commute.

Answer (score 1):

It probably does not have a name because this method does not generalize very well, it is in this generality restricted to linear DE with constant coefficients where other methods can be applied more mechanically. The justification of these methods may use the full factorization in its proof construction.

Also some special examples of other linear DE can be factorized. The method of reduction of order reconstructs a factorization with one first-order factor from a given solution of the homogeneous DE.

What you do practically is to transform the given DE into a system of first order using intermediate functions that are especially adapted to the structure of the DE, $z=(D+3)y=y'+3y$, $e^t=(D+1)z=z'+z$.

In other situations one can find such special first-order systems even if no complete factorization is available. For example in the van der Pol oscillator $x''+\mu(x^2-1)x'+x=0$ one can combine the derivatives into the intermediate variable as $\mu v=x'+\mu(x^3/3-x)$ so that $v'=-x/\mu$.